# why in my pycharm IDE template tags intellisense or html tags intellisense do not work?

Tags: django, pycharm

there is no suggestion for template tags or html tags what should i do ?

[image: what's the problem]

Comment: Shouldn't you write template tags between `{% ... %}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure that you've told pycharm that you're creating a django project;

- [Django Framework settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/django-support.html)
- [Template language settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/template-languages.html#9942e1a2)

Then bare in mind that django tags start with `{%` . Your template might look like this;

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div id="query_area" class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Playground</h2>
        <p>
```

The django docs for templates may be of use to you; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/templates/

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm will automcomplete this templatetag when you type `{%` before the tag you want to use.

Pycharm will also autocomplete any custom tags you register in your applications